# What does "s" in keeps mean?

Tags: verbs

In the sentence *What keeps us healthy and happy*, what does "s" in "keeps" stand for? it's not a singular verb! I don't understand the usage of "s." Can you explain that? 
Thanks

Comment: 'What' is considered singular here and 'keeps' applies to 'what' -- 'keeps' is not applied to 'healthy and happy' in this sentence. If you were to attach a plural noun like 'things' to 'what' then 'keeps' will be applied as **'keep'** to that plural noun, as in ***what things keep us*** healthy and happy?

Comment: @EnglishStudent Thanks, "What" is considered singular is the answer:) Would you please give me a link to study further about this?

Comment: Your text isn't a sentence (it's just a noun phrase). *There is **a** thing which keeps us healthy and happy, but **it is** unspecified in your text* (where ***it*** is singular: ***the thing*** which keeps us healthy and happy).

Comment: Sorry I dont know where to find a link for this particular construction, but you just keep reading as much English as you can -- and remember, 99.9% of your questions can be cleared right here at English Language Learners or English Language & Usage 'twin websites'!

Comment: Is it supposed to be a question? If so, where is the question mark at the end?

Comment: It is not difficult to find a resource on the internet where you can learn to conjugate an English verb like _keep._ There is nothing difficult or advanced here. It isn't a difficult construction. _Keeps_ is the third person singular form of the present tense of the verb _keep._

Answer (score 3):

Well, yes, it is a singular verb, but the understanding of it as such is idiomatic. It may be helpful to think of this sentence as *What thing keeps us healthy and happy?* We understand *what* to be asking about *something* by default, not *some group of things*.

In purely logical terms, *what* could be understood to be asking about a plurality, but again, we don't think of it that way. If we wanted to ask about a plurality, we would specifically ask *What things keep us healthy and happy?* or *What are the things that keep us healthy and happy?*

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of simple grammar, the 's' is added to create the right [conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation). A few examples:

Present tense
 - I/you/they *keep*
 - He/she/it *keep**s***

Past tense
 - I (have) kept

'What' can be considered singular here, despite the fact that the answer could be *Fruits and vegetables keep us happy and healthy*.